# Where do i locate ULS Logs for Sharepoint 2013 Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, uls, logs

I have Medium Size farm with 2 App Server 3 wfe 3 workflow and 1 sql server.

2 app server host central admin, 3 wfe host 5 web applications. I recently encountered error and correlation ID was generated at given time related to Site template not being able to get saved. I went through ULS logs in all 3 WFE but couldn't find Correlation ids.

Am i looking at wrong place or something else is going wrong. Can anyone advise where would the error be listed if one of the site collection encounters error.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiago Give the correct information, I want to add couple of things.

- sometime you run the Above Powershell(merge-Splog) but does not return any result. You need to add Start time & End time Parameter(you can timing in the error screen)

  > Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log" -Correlation
  >   "5ca5269c-8de5-4091-3f1b-f179af4d5121" -Overwrite -StartTime
  >   "06/09/2008 16:00" - EndTime "06/09/2008 16:15"
- If error within WebPart(Custom), it will not report in the logs unless you have write some sort of loggin in it.

  -

Answer (score 3):

I was about to give a very simplistic answer when I bumped into [this](http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/An-Even-Better-Way-to-Get-the-Real-SharePoint-Error#.U-ACEmIaySM) post.

Apparently you can use the Merge-SPLogFile cmdlet to return all the log data for a given correlation id, without knowing the frontend server.

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path ".\error.log" -Correlation "5ca5269c-8de5-4091-3f1b-f179af4d5121"
```